# Images With JavaFX are not showing up

Tags: image, javafx

I am pretty new a Java, and this class is going through JavaFX. Right now it is ok until I put in a simple Image. The main body shows up, yet the image does not show up. Here is my example. I have tried to put the image in different places, and it still do not work. I am confused about how to enter an image into JavaFX. Thanks Reed.

```
package chapter14;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;

public class ShowImage extends Application {

    @Override 
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        Pane pane = new HBox(10);
        pane.setPadding(new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5));
        //Image image = new Image("file:Testing/Listing_14/src/listing_14            /Listing/image/th.gif");   //Testing
        Image image = new Image("file:image/th.gif");
        pane.getChildren().add(new ImageView(image));

        ImageView imageView2 = new ImageView(image);
        imageView2.setFitHeight(100);
        imageView2.setFitWidth(100);
        pane.getChildren().add(imageView2);   

        ImageView imageView3 = new ImageView(image);
        imageView3.setRotate(90);
        pane.getChildren().add(imageView3);     

        // Create a scene and place it in the stage
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane);
        primaryStage.setTitle("ShowImage"); // Set the stage title
        primaryStage.setScene(scene); // Place the scene in the stage
        primaryStage.show(); // Display the stage
    }

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

}

Comment: Even though `Pane pane = new HBox(10);` is valid code. I would not do it for the sake of code clarity.

Comment: maybe it's a path problem can you post your project file structure

Comment: If your image file is a _resource_ then you should omit the scheme (i.e. remove the `file:` bit) or use `getClass().getResource(...).toExternalForm()` to get an absolute URL. The former is allowed because a scheme-less URL is interpreted as a "package path", same as with `ClassLoader#getResource`. In other words, the resource is searched for relative to the root of the classpath.

Answer (score 0):

You should try:

```
    File file = new File("YourFilePath/Image.png");
    Image image = new Image(file.toURI().toString());
```

In stead of :

```
    Image image = new Image("file:image/th.gif");
```

I think that might solve the problem, otherwise you should look more into what really is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine I guess it's just a path problem your project structure should be like this

```
Project
|------image
        |-----th.gif
|------src
        |-----chapter14
               |---------ShowImage.java
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work when `th.gif` is in the same folder as the java code:

```
URL url = Images.class.getResource("th.gif");
Image imageFromSourceFolder = new Image(url.openStream());
ImageView view = new ImageView(imageFromSourceFolder);
```